# SQLite not opening database file in iOS8 Xcode 6.0.1

Tags: sqlite, ios8, xcode6

I have a simple if clause:

```
if (sqlite3_open([[DBAccess getDBPath] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
```

This condition works in iOS 7.1 or older but not in iOS 8.

Any idea?

Thank you guys.

Comment: How do you determine your path? How can people help you when you do not provide enough information?

Comment: Sorry @LeoNatan as the determination of the path works in previous iOS version I didn't think that could be relevant but here is the code how I get the path: `+ (NSString *)getDBPath {
        NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle]  resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];
    NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DB.SQL"];
    return filePath = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SalesApp.sql"];
}`

Comment: There is your problem.

Comment: Add the information to your question. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder hierarchy has changed under iOS8.

The Documents directory is now located differently than before. Use `[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject]` to retrieve the path of the path.